# ResourceResolverFactory getServiceResourceResolver throws Exception in AEM 6.1

Tags: aem, sling

I want to write some data to AEM, and the below code works fine for me in AEM 6.0 but not in AEM 6.1 , always throws a Login Exception as follows:

"*Login Exception when obtaining a CRX User for the Service:'writeService'.org.apache.sling.api.resource.LoginException: Cannot derive user name for bundle group.tti.commons-service [395] and sub service writeService*"

OSGI Config:

[image]

Code in my class:

```
import javax.jcr.Session;
import org.apache.sling.api.resource.ResourceResolver;
import org.apache.sling.api.resource.ResourceResolverFactory;
....
@Reference
private ResourceResolverFactory factory;
private ResourceResolver resourceResolverWriter;
private static Session adminSession;
...
...
Map<String, Object> param = new HashMap<String, Object>();        
    param.put(ResourceResolverFactory.SUBSERVICE, "writeService");
try {
  resourceResolverWriter = factory.getServiceResourceResolver(param);            
  adminSession = resourceResolverWriter.adaptTo(Session.class);
...
} catch (LoginException e) {
...
}
```

Am i missing anything on AEM 6.1?

Comment: I'm assuming that the reference to resourceResolverWriter here is a typo. Otherwise this code wouldn't even compile.

Comment: Updated code in the original post.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

With Justin's advice, i tried and found the solution. Posting so can be beneficial for others.

Goal: To write data/nodes to content (specifically to /etc/userdata) when a user logs in.

We can achieve this in 2 ways (either way, the user needs to be a 'system user')

### **Process 1:**

Step 1: Use in-built system user in OSGI configuration. In OSGI select **Apache Sling Service User Mapper Service**

`group.abc.commons-service:writeService=oauthservice` (where `oauthservice` is a system user)

Step 2: Assign that system user the permissions to access the content folder.

[image]

You see the system users in CRX at: `/home/users/system`

### **Process 2:**

*Step 1*: Create a new system user. to do this
Open http://localhost:4502/crx/explorer/index.jsp

```
1. Login as admin 
2. Open 'User Administration
3. Select 'Create System User'
4. Enter "user id"
5. Hit the Green button (you will not se a save button :)`
```

I have created **abcwriteservice** user

Step 2: Go to Permissions, and for the user **abcwriteservice** give Permissions to access the folder where you'd like to write. (In this example: `/etc/userdata` )
[image]

Step 3: Open OSGI console and go to **Apache Sling Service User Mapper Service** to define the service-user mapping.

Example: `group.commons-service:writeService=abcwriteservice`

[image]

Step 4: In code, i added extra parameter, as:

```java
Map<String, Object> param = new HashMap<String, Object>();
param.put(ResourceResolverFactory.SUBSERVICE, "writeService");

try {
    resourceResolverWriter = factory.getServiceResourceResolver(param);

    if (resourceResolverWriter == null)
        throw new Exception("Could not obtain a CRX User for the Service:'writeService'");

    Node usersRootNode = adminSession.getNode("/etc/userdata/users");
}
```

Comment: How do I do this inside a Sling Model? Like I want to force the Sling model to use my service user to login to JCR

Comment: I've not tried but this may help https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2495543

Comment: Thanks @Suren This did help, my approach is wrong, such operations shouldn't happen in a sling model. I changed my approach and things worked. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 21):

In AEM 6.1, service users must be system users, which effectively means that their node in the JCR is of type rep:SystemUser. These users **cannot** be used to log in normally, only by background processes. The admin user is **not** a system user, so you cannot use the admin user in a service user mapping like this. You have to create a new system user and assign them the appropriate permissions.

If you would like to read more of the background on this change, take a look at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SLING-3854.

Comment: How can we create a new system user?

Comment: @suren My recomendation would be this Access control tool for AEM https://github.com/Netcentric/accesscontroltool

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you are planning a future migration to AEM 6.2, consider using ACS Commons to facilitate the creation and availability of system users. It eliminates all this manual process which can be error-prone.

https://adobe-consulting-services.github.io/acs-aem-commons/features/ensure-service-users/index.html

Answer (score -5):

insted of making session like:

```
adminSession = resourceResolverWriter.adaptTo(Session.class);`
```

make Session like below ,hopefully  Login exception will not occur

```
final Session session;
session= resourceResolver.adaptTo(Session.class);
```

This happen because resourceResolverWriter is not implicit object.

Comment: I don't think we can assign a value to session again once it is defined as final. Anyways, I have updated the code in my original post.

Comment: That's not correct. See Surendra's and Justice's answers.