# Cannot derive user name for bundle org.demo.anthony.mybundle.core [446] and sub service null

Tags: aem, osgi-bundle

I have a bundle that was working completely fine in AEM 6. I just upgraded to AEM 6.1 and when I deploy the bundle, I'm getting the error below:

> javax.jcr.LoginException: Cannot derive user name for bundle
>   org.demo.anthony.mybundle.core [446] and sub service null     at
>   org.apache.sling.jcr.base.AbstractSlingRepository2.loginService(AbstractSlingRepository2.java:336)
>     at
>   org.demo.anthony.mybundle.core.impl.EvernoteSyncServiceImpl.getSession(EvernoteSyncServiceImpl.java:108)
>     at
>   org.demo.anthony.mybundle.core.impl.EvernoteSyncServiceImpl.syncNotes(EvernoteSyncServiceImpl.java:201)
>     at
>   org.demo.anthony.mybundle.core.impl.EvernoteSyncServiceImpl.syncWebClipperNotes(EvernoteSyncServiceImpl.java:174)
>     at
>   org.demo.nennig.evernote.core.impl.schedulers.EvernoteSyncTask.run(EvernoteSyncTask.java:96)
>     at
>   org.apache.sling.commons.scheduler.impl.QuartzJobExecutor.execute(QuartzJobExecutor.java:105)
>     at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

This is how I'm getting hold of the session (this is line 108 in the code as referenced in the stacktrace):

```
session = repository.loginService(null, null);
```

Comment: This looks like a problem with service user mappings. Have you checked your _Apache Sling Service User Mapper Service_ configuration? Are the mappings still there after the migration?

Answer (score 1):

Until AEM 6.0, the services were allowed to be accessed by default "admin" user. From 6.1, you have to specify a "system user" and/or another user for a specific service. You can define these mapping in *Sling Service User Mapper*

We had similar issues and below are some of my solutions, see if they'll help:

[ResourceResolverFactory getServiceResourceResolver throws Exception in AEM 6.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31350548/resourceresolverfactory-getserviceresourceresolver-throws-exception-in-aem-6-1/31394583#31394583)

[How to create a system user (rep:SystemUser) in AEM 6.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31388591/how-to-create-a-system-user-repsystemuser-in-aem-6-1/31435291#31435291)

One more example from Adobe:
https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/querying-experience-manager-sling.html