# POST Servlet not able to access DAM(or anything at all)

Tags: jsp, servlets, post, aem

I have written a Servlet that gets the links of assets from the DAM based on AEM Tags.
The servlet is working fine in author for GET/POST but it raises IllegalStateException when I try to access it on a publish instance in higher environment(settings are done for security). Although GET requests in the same servlet are going through which also access the DAM. This makes me believe that it has to do with POST servlet configs and access controls rather than accessing the DAM, but in the trace I see code breaking up on the same line where it tries to access the DAM.

I have the path Servlet Config and the application is running using admin user on the server, so I believe it should have access to the DAM.

This is the piece of code which gets the assets and which is shown as a part of the stack trace.

```
Iterator<Resource> it = tm.find(DOCS_LOCATION_DAM, productLang, false);
```

This is the exception

```
22.01.2016 16:38:29.959 *ERROR* [155.64.222.67 [1453505907153] POST /bin/xxxxxxxxx/productlicense HTTP/1.1] org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl service: Uncaught Throwable
java.lang.IllegalStateException: This session has been closed
at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:150)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.core.ContentSessionImpl.checkLive(ContentSessionImpl.java:85)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.core.MutableRoot.checkLive(MutableRoot.java:172)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.core.MutableTree.beforeRead(MutableTree.java:403)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.core.MutableTree.exists(MutableTree.java:102)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.query.ast.SelectorImpl.next(SelectorImpl.java:423)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.query.QueryImpl$RowIterator.fetchNext(QueryImpl.java:644)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.query.QueryImpl$RowIterator.hasNext(QueryImpl.java:664)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.query.FilterIterators$SortIterator.init(FilterIterators.java:203)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.query.FilterIterators$SortIterator.hasNext(FilterIterators.java:237)
at com.google.common.collect.Iterators$5.hasNext(Iterators.java:542)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.query.FilterIterators$DistinctIterator.fetchNext(FilterIterators.java:137)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.query.FilterIterators$DistinctIterator.hasNext(FilterIterators.java:151)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.query.FilterIterators$SortIterator.init(FilterIterators.java:203)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.query.FilterIterators$SortIterator.hasNext(FilterIterators.java:237)
at com.google.common.collect.Iterators$5.hasNext(Iterators.java:542)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.query.FilterIterators$DistinctIterator.fetchNext(FilterIterators.java:137)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.query.FilterIterators$DistinctIterator.hasNext(FilterIterators.java:151)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.query.FilterIterators$SortIterator.init(FilterIterators.java:203)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.query.FilterIterators$SortIterator.hasNext(FilterIterators.java:237)
at com.google.common.collect.Iterators$5.hasNext(Iterators.java:542)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.query.FilterIterators$DistinctIterator.fetchNext(FilterIterators.java:137)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.query.FilterIterators$DistinctIterator.hasNext(FilterIterators.java:151)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.query.FilterIterators$SortIterator.init(FilterIterators.java:203)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.query.FilterIterators$SortIterator.hasNext(FilterIterators.java:237)
at com.google.common.collect.Iterators$5.hasNext(Iterators.java:542)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.query.FilterIterators$DistinctIterator.fetchNext(FilterIterators.java:137)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.query.FilterIterators$DistinctIterator.hasNext(FilterIterators.java:151)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.query.FilterIterators$SortIterator.init(FilterIterators.java:203)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.query.FilterIterators$SortIterator.hasNext(FilterIterators.java:237)
at com.google.common.collect.Iterators$5.hasNext(Iterators.java:542)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.query.FilterIterators$DistinctIterator.fetchNext(FilterIterators.java:137)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.query.FilterIterators$DistinctIterator.hasNext(FilterIterators.java:151)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.query.FilterIterators$SortIterator.init(FilterIterators.java:203)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.query.FilterIterators$SortIterator.hasNext(FilterIterators.java:237)
at com.google.common.collect.Iterators$5.hasNext(Iterators.java:542)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.query.FilterIterators$DistinctIterator.fetchNext(FilterIterators.java:137)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.query.FilterIterators$DistinctIterator.hasNext(FilterIterators.java:151)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.query.FilterIterators$SortIterator.init(FilterIterators.java:203)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.query.FilterIterators$SortIterator.hasNext(FilterIterators.java:237)
at com.google.common.collect.Iterators$5.hasNext(Iterators.java:542)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.query.FilterIterators$DistinctIterator.fetchNext(FilterIterators.java:137)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.query.FilterIterators$DistinctIterator.hasNext(FilterIterators.java:151)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.query.FilterIterators$SortIterator.init(FilterIterators.java:203)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.query.FilterIterators$SortIterator.hasNext(FilterIterators.java:237)
at com.google.common.collect.Iterators$5.hasNext(Iterators.java:542)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.query.FilterIterators$DistinctIterator.fetchNext(FilterIterators.java:137)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.query.FilterIterators$DistinctIterator.hasNext(FilterIterators.java:151)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.query.FilterIterators$SortIterator.init(FilterIterators.java:203)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.query.FilterIterators$SortIterator.hasNext(FilterIterators.java:237)
at com.google.common.collect.Iterators$5.hasNext(Iterators.java:542)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.query.FilterIterators$DistinctIterator.fetchNext(FilterIterators.java:137)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.query.FilterIterators$DistinctIterator.hasNext(FilterIterators.java:151)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.query.FilterIterators$SortIterator.init(FilterIterators.java:203)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.query.FilterIterators$SortIterator.hasNext(FilterIterators.java:237)
at com.google.common.collect.Iterators$5.hasNext(Iterators.java:542)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.query.FilterIterators$DistinctIterator.fetchNext(FilterIterators.java:137)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.query.FilterIterators$DistinctIterator.hasNext(FilterIterators.java:151)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.query.FilterIterators$SortIterator.init(FilterIterators.java:203)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.query.FilterIterators$SortIterator.hasNext(FilterIterators.java:237)
at com.google.common.collect.Iterators$5.hasNext(Iterators.java:542)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.query.FilterIterators$DistinctIterator.fetchNext(FilterIterators.java:137)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.query.FilterIterators$DistinctIterator.hasNext(FilterIterators.java:151)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.query.FilterIterators$SortIterator.init(FilterIterators.java:203)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.query.FilterIterators$SortIterator.hasNext(FilterIterators.java:237)
at com.google.common.collect.Iterators$5.hasNext(Iterators.java:542)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.query.FilterIterators$DistinctIterator.fetchNext(FilterIterators.java:137)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.query.FilterIterators$DistinctIterator.hasNext(FilterIterators.java:151)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.query.FilterIterators$SortIterator.init(FilterIterators.java:203)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.query.FilterIterators$SortIterator.hasNext(FilterIterators.java:237)
at com.google.common.collect.Iterators$5.hasNext(Iterators.java:542)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.query.FilterIterators$DistinctIterator.fetchNext(FilterIterators.java:137)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.query.FilterIterators$DistinctIterator.hasNext(FilterIterators.java:151)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.query.FilterIterators$SortIterator.init(FilterIterators.java:203)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.query.FilterIterators$SortIterator.hasNext(FilterIterators.java:237)
at com.google.common.collect.Iterators$5.hasNext(Iterators.java:542)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.query.FilterIterators$DistinctIterator.fetchNext(FilterIterators.java:137)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.query.FilterIterators$DistinctIterator.hasNext(FilterIterators.java:151)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.query.FilterIterators$SortIterator.init(FilterIterators.java:203)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.query.FilterIterators$SortIterator.hasNext(FilterIterators.java:237)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.query.QueryResultImpl$3.fetch(QueryResultImpl.java:182)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.query.QueryResultImpl$3.<init>(QueryResultImpl.java:177)
at org.apache.jackrabbit.oak.jcr.query.QueryResultImpl.getNodes(QueryResultImpl.java:171)
at com.day.cq.tagging.impl.JcrTagManagerImpl.findNodes(JcrTagManagerImpl.java:1343)
at com.day.cq.tagging.impl.JcrTagManagerImpl.find(JcrTagManagerImpl.java:518)
at com.day.cq.tagging.impl.JcrTagManagerImpl.find(JcrTagManagerImpl.java:425)
at com.xxxxxxxxx.core.impl.servlets.ProductLicenseServlet.getLicences(ProductLicenseServlet.java:269)
at com.xxxxxxxxx.core.impl.servlets.ProductLicenseServlet.getLicenses(ProductLicenseServlet.java:214)
at com.xxxxxxxxx.core.impl.servlets.ProductLicenseServlet.doPost(ProductLicenseServlet.java:92)
at org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingAllMethodsServlet.mayService(SlingAllMethodsServlet.java:148)
at org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingSafeMethodsServlet.service(SlingSafeMethodsServlet.java:344)
at org.apache.sling.api.servlets.SlingSafeMethodsServlet.service(SlingSafeMethodsServlet.java:375)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.request.RequestData.service(RequestData.java:533)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.SlingComponentFilterChain.render(SlingComponentFilterChain.java:45)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:64)
at com.day.cq.personalization.impl.TargetComponentFilter.doFilter(TargetComponentFilter.java:96)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDebugFilter.doFilter(WCMDebugFilter.java:146)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMComponentFilter.filterRootInclude(WCMComponentFilter.java:357)
at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMComponentFilter.doFilter(WCMComponentFilter.java:166)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl.processComponent(SlingRequestProcessorImpl.java:282)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.RequestSlingFilterChain.render(RequestSlingFilterChain.java:49)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:64)
at com.adobe.granite.resourceresolverhelper.impl.ResourceResolverHelperImpl.doFilter(ResourceResolverHelperImpl.java:81)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
at com.adobe.cq.dam.s7imaging.impl.auth.MemoryTokenAuthHandler.doFilter(MemoryTokenAuthHandler.java:156)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
at org.apache.sling.i18n.impl.I18NFilter.doFilter(I18NFilter.java:128)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.AuthoringUIModeServiceImpl.doFilter(AuthoringUIModeServiceImpl.java:349)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
at org.apache.sling.rewriter.impl.RewriterFilter.doFilter(RewriterFilter.java:83)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.warp.TimeWarpFilter.doFilter(TimeWarpFilter.java:106)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
at com.day.cq.wcm.mobile.core.impl.redirect.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:295)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
at com.xxxxxxxxx.core.impl.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:50)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
at com.xxxxxxxxx.xxxxinfo.core.impl.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:50)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
at com.cognifide.slice.core.internal.filter.ContextRequestFilter.doFilter(ContextRequestFilter.java:90)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
at com.adobe.cq.social.commons.cors.CORSAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(CORSAuthenticationFilter.java:91)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.debug.RequestProgressTrackerLogFilter.doFilter(RequestProgressTrackerLogFilter.java:95)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
at com.day.cq.wcm.foundation.forms.impl.FormsHandlingServlet.doFilter(FormsHandlingServlet.java:251)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
at com.day.cq.theme.impl.ThemeResolverFilter.doFilter(ThemeResolverFilter.java:76)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
at com.adobe.granite.optout.impl.OptOutFilter.doFilter(OptOutFilter.java:74)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMRequestFilter.doFilter(WCMRequestFilter.java:90)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
at com.adobe.cq.history.impl.HistoryRequestFilter.doFilter(HistoryRequestFilter.java:107)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
at com.day.cq.wcm.designimporter.CanvasPageDeleteRequestFilter.doFilter(CanvasPageDeleteRequestFilter.java:88)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
at com.adobe.granite.httpcache.impl.InnerCacheFilter.doFilter(InnerCacheFilter.java:77)
at com.adobe.granite.httpcache.impl.InnerCacheFilter.doFilter(InnerCacheFilter.java:56)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
at org.apache.sling.bgservlets.impl.BackgroundServletStarterFilter.doFilter(BackgroundServletStarterFilter.java:135)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
at com.adobe.cq.social.commons.security.SaferSlingPostServlet.doFilter(SaferSlingPostServlet.java:132)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
at com.adobe.granite.requests.logging.impl.RequestLoggerImpl.doFilter(RequestLoggerImpl.java:124)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl.doProcessRequest(SlingRequestProcessorImpl.java:151)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingMainServlet.service(SlingMainServlet.java:217)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:339)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:300)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.ServletPipeline.handle(ServletPipeline.java:93)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:50)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
at org.apache.sling.i18n.impl.I18NFilter.doFilter(I18NFilter.java:128)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
at com.adobe.granite.license.impl.LicenseCheckFilter.doFilter(LicenseCheckFilter.java:300)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
at org.apache.felix.http.sslfilter.internal.SslFilter.doFilter(SslFilter.java:89)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
at org.apache.sling.security.impl.ReferrerFilter.doFilter(ReferrerFilter.java:290)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
at org.apache.felix.http.sslfilter.internal.SslFilter.doFilter(SslFilter.java:55)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
at org.apache.sling.featureflags.impl.FeatureManager.doFilter(FeatureManager.java:115)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.log.RequestLoggerFilter.doFilter(RequestLoggerFilter.java:75)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.FilterPipeline.dispatch(FilterPipeline.java:76)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.Dispatcher.dispatch(Dispatcher.java:49)
at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.DispatcherServlet.service(DispatcherServlet.java:67)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:684)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:501)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:229)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:428)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:982)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1043)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:865)
at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:240)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:667)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Could you post code. you should look into the config differences between the environment where its working and the said higher environment.

Answer (score 1):

Few things you can check:

1. By default "admin" account is used to access the resources. From 6.1 this is not the case. Are you using AEM 6.1?
2. Check the permissions to the resource (Path) you are trying to access. Is it under "everyone" group? Or? This maybe one possibility the resource is working in your DEV. In higher environments this may not be the case.

   One way i came around this issue is to use a custom service-user. I [posted a solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31350548/resourceresolverfactory-getserviceresourceresolver-throws-exception-in-aem-6-1/31394583#31394583) see if it helps.
3. If you do not have access to higher-environments, then ask AEM-Admin to (a) either assign permissions to a specific user to access that DAM resource, so you can use that user in the solution above, (b)Or have "everyone" group have access to that DAM resource.