# best way to access JCR data AEM 6.0/ cq5

Tags: aem

I would like to know, in the following three ways, which one should be used to get access to jcr data.

```
resolverFactory.getServiceResourceResolver(Map authInfo);
resolverFactory.getResourceResolver(Map authInfo);
session.getService('serviceName', null);
```

Could please share knowledge on these specific methods and how to provide authInfo and in what scenarios each of these methods used.

It seems, from AEM 6.0 onwards the `getAdministrativeResourceResolver` method is deprecated because of security reasons ??

Thank you,
Sri

Answer (score 0):

From AEM 6.1 you cannot use "admin" to access the nodes. I have detailed a solution here [ResourceResolverFactory getServiceResourceResolver throws Exception in AEM 6.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31350548/resourceresolverfactory-getserviceresourceresolver-throws-exception-in-aem-6-1/31394583#31394583)

And to here's what i have done to Read and Write data to JCR.

```
public class InteractHelper {

  @Reference
  private ResourceResolverFactory resolverFactory;
  private ResourceResolver resourceResolver;

  @Activate
  private void activate(ComponentContext context) {
  ...
  Map<String, Object> param = new HashMap<String, Object>();
  // AEM_SUBSERVICE is the service name that you need to define from the OSGI                 
  param.put(ResourceResolverFactory.SUBSERVICE, AEM_SUBSERVICE);

  try {
        resourceResolver = resolverFactory.getServiceResourceResolver(param);
  ...

  }

  /** Write data to a node */
  public void saveToRepository(ResourceResolver resourceResolver, String dataString) throws Exception {
     Session session = resourceResolver.adaptTo(Session.class);

     Node userNode;
     Node userJcrContentNode;
     String nodePath="";    

     if (session!=null) {
        Node usersRootNode = session.getNode(USERS_ROOT_FOLDER);
        userNode = session.getNode(usersRootNode.getPath() + "/" + "suren");

        if (userNode!=null) {                
            nodePath = userNode.getPath();
        }

        if (!session.itemExists(nodePath)) {
            userNode = usersRootNode.addNode("suren", "cq:Page");
            userJcrContentNode = userNode.addNode("jcr:content", "cq:PageContent");
        }

        if(!session.itemExists(nodePath+"/jcr:content")){
            userJcrContentNode = userNode.addNode("jcr:content", "cq:PageContent");    
        }
        userJcrContentNode = userNode.getNode("jcr:content");
        userJcrContentNode.setProperty("abc-shoppingcart",dataString);

        // Save the session changes and log out
        session.save();       
        session.logout();
     }
 }

 /** Read data from Node */
 public void readFromRepository(ResourceResolver resourceResolver, String encodedShoppingCartString) throws Exception {
    Session session = resourceResolver.adaptTo(Session.class);

    if (session!=null) {
        Node usersRootNode = session.getNode(USERS_ROOT_FOLDER);

        Node userNode = usersRootNode.addNode("suren", "cq:Page");
        Node userJcrContentNode = userNode.addNode("jcr:content", "cq:PageContent");

        userJcrContentNode = userNode.getNode("jcr:content");
        userJcrContentNode.setProperty("abc-shoppingcart",dataString);

        // Save the session changes and log out
        session.save();       
        session.logout();
    }
}
```