# AEM 6.1 anonymous read access to /etc was removed. How to handle this?

Tags: adobe, aem, sling

There's a code like this in my project to read some configuration from /etc/my-config-path:

```
Resource res = resource.getResourceResolver().getResource("/etc/my-config-path");
```

On AEM 5.6.1 it works correctly since anonymous user has access to entire /etc. On AEM 6.1 res is null since anonymous user has no access to /etc.

I can see two possible solutions:

1. Give anonymous user read permission to /etc/my-config-path explicitly
2. Use `repository.loginAdministrative(null);` to access the resource with admin permissions (but I see some people not recommending this approach on AEM 6.1).

What is your thoughts on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In AEM 6.1 access to /etc by default to admin was removed. I posted a [solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31350548/resourceresolverfactory-getserviceresourceresolver-throws-exception-in-aem-6-1/31394583#31394583), describes how to create a service user.

Comment: I believe this is the best solution I've found for my problem so far. Thank you.