# How to create user and group in aem6.2 programmatically with ACL permissions?

Tags: java, aem, jcr, sling, aem-6

Is it possible to create Group and User in **AEM6.2** by using  Jackrabbit User Manager API with permissions.
I have just followed below URL's but the code is throwing some exception :

1. https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/jackrabbit-users.html
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38259047/how-to-give-permission-all-in-aem-through-programatically
3. [ResourceResolverFactory getServiceResourceResolver throws Exception in AEM 6.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31350548/resourceresolverfactory-getserviceresourceresolver-throws-exception-in-aem-6-1)

As [`getAdministrativeResourceResolver(Map)`](https://sling.apache.org/apidocs/sling7/org/apache/sling/api/resource/ResourceResolverFactory.html#getAdministrativeResourceResolver-java.util.Map-) method is deprecated then how can we use [`getServiceResourceResolver(Map)`](https://sling.apache.org/apidocs/sling7/org/apache/sling/api/resource/ResourceResolverFactory.html#getServiceResourceResolver-java.util.Map-) method instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sharing my solution which will be helpful for others.

Following is the code using [`getServiceResourceResolver(Map)`](https://sling.apache.org/apidocs/sling7/org/apache/sling/api/resource/ResourceResolverFactory.html#getServiceResourceResolver-java.util.Map-) method for creating Group first and then User and then add user into group with ACL privileges and permission:

```
public void createGroupUser(SlingHttpServletRequest request) {
    String userName = request.getParameter("userName");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");
    String groupName = request.getParameter("groupName");

    Session session = null;
    ResourceResolver resourceResolver = null;
    try {
        Map<String, Object> param = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        param.put(ResourceResolverFactory.SUBSERVICE, "datawrite");
        resourceResolver = resourceResolverFactory.getServiceResourceResolver(param);
        session = resourceResolver.adaptTo(Session.class);

        // Create UserManager Object
        final UserManager userManager = AccessControlUtil.getUserManager(session);

        // Create a Group
        Group group = null;
        if (userManager.getAuthorizable(groupName) == null) {
            group = userManager.createGroup(groupName);

            ValueFactory valueFactory = session.getValueFactory();
            Value groupNameValue = valueFactory.createValue(groupName, PropertyType.STRING);
            group.setProperty("./profile/givenName", groupNameValue);
            session.save();

            log.info("---> {} Group successfully created.", group.getID());
        } else {
            log.info("---> Group already exist..");
        }

        // Create a User
        User user = null;
        if (userManager.getAuthorizable(userName) == null) {
            user = userManager.createUser(userName, password);

            ValueFactory valueFactory = session.getValueFactory();
            Value firstNameValue = valueFactory.createValue("Arpit", PropertyType.STRING);
            user.setProperty("./profile/givenName", firstNameValue);

            Value lastNameValue = valueFactory.createValue("Bora", PropertyType.STRING);
            user.setProperty("./profile/familyName", lastNameValue);

            Value emailValue = valueFactory.createValue("arpit.p.bora@gmail.com", PropertyType.STRING);
            user.setProperty("./profile/email", emailValue);
            session.save();

            // Add User to Group
            Group addUserToGroup = (Group) (userManager.getAuthorizable(groupName));
            addUserToGroup.addMember(userManager.getAuthorizable(userName));
            session.save();

            // set Resource-based ACLs
            String nodePath = user.getPath();
            setAclPrivileges(nodePath, session);

            log.info("---> {} User successfully created and added into group.", user.getID());
        } else {
            log.info("---> User already exist..");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.info("---> Not able to perform User Management..");
        log.info("---> Exception.." + e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        if (session != null && session.isLive()) {
            session.logout();
        }
        if (resourceResolver != null)
            resourceResolver.close();
    }
}

public static void setAclPrivileges(String path, Session session) {
    try {
        AccessControlManager aMgr = session.getAccessControlManager();

        // create a privilege set
        Privilege[] privileges = new Privilege[] { 
                aMgr.privilegeFromName(Privilege.JCR_VERSION_MANAGEMENT),
                aMgr.privilegeFromName(Privilege.JCR_MODIFY_PROPERTIES),
                aMgr.privilegeFromName(Privilege.JCR_ADD_CHILD_NODES),
                aMgr.privilegeFromName(Privilege.JCR_LOCK_MANAGEMENT),
                aMgr.privilegeFromName(Privilege.JCR_NODE_TYPE_MANAGEMENT),
                aMgr.privilegeFromName(Replicator.REPLICATE_PRIVILEGE) };

        AccessControlList acl;
        try {
            // get first applicable policy (for nodes w/o a policy)
            acl = (AccessControlList) aMgr.getApplicablePolicies(path).nextAccessControlPolicy();
        } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
            // else node already has a policy, get that one
            acl = (AccessControlList) aMgr.getPolicies(path)[0];
        }
        // remove all existing entries
        for (AccessControlEntry e : acl.getAccessControlEntries()) {
            acl.removeAccessControlEntry(e);
        }
        // add a new one for the special "everyone" principal
        acl.addAccessControlEntry(EveryonePrincipal.getInstance(), privileges);

        // the policy must be re-set
        aMgr.setPolicy(path, acl);

        // and the session must be saved for the changes to be applied
        session.save();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.info("---> Not able to perform ACL Privileges..");
        log.info("---> Exception.." + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

In code **"datawrite"** is a service mapping which is mapped with system user in **"Apache Sling Service User Mapper Service"** which is configurable in the OSGI configuration admin interface.

For more detail about system user check link - [How to Create System User in AEM?](http://www.aemcq5tutorials.com/tutorials/create-system-user-in-aem/)

Comment: Where do you at this code so that that it will be executed on startup of the AEM instance?

Answer (score 0):

I am providing this code direcly from a training of an official Adobe channel, and it is based on AEM 6.1. So I assume this might be the best practice.

```
    private void modifyPermissions() {
    Session adminSession = null;
    try{
        adminSession = repository.loginService(null, repository.getDefaultWorkspace());

        UserManager userMgr= ((org.apache.jackrabbit.api.JackrabbitSession)adminSession).getUserManager();
        AccessControlManager accessControlManager = adminSession.getAccessControlManager();

        Authorizable denyAccess = userMgr.getAuthorizable("deny-access");

        AccessControlPolicyIterator policyIterator =
                accessControlManager.getApplicablePolicies(CONTENT_GEOMETRIXX_FR);
        AccessControlList acl;
        try{
            acl=(JackrabbitAccessControlList) policyIterator.nextAccessControlPolicy();             
        }catch(NoSuchElementException nse){
            acl=(JackrabbitAccessControlList)  accessControlManager.getPolicies(CONTENT_GEOMETRIXX_FR)[0];

        }

        Privilege[] privileges = {accessControlManager.privilegeFromName(Privilege.JCR_READ)};
        acl.addAccessControlEntry(denyAccess.getPrincipal(), privileges);
        accessControlManager.setPolicy(CONTENT_GEOMETRIXX_FR, acl);
        adminSession.save();
    }catch (RepositoryException e){
        LOGGER.error("**************************Repo Exception", e);
    }finally{
        if (adminSession != null)
            adminSession.logout();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your sugession Vinicius Maciel, But I want to create Group first and then User and then i want to add user to group using getServiceResourceResolver(map) or loginService("datawrite",null) method with ACL permissions.
Is there is any way to create Group using getServiceResourceResolver(map) or loginService("datawrite",null) method?